# Auto-import un-implemented methods when implementing Dart List

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I am implementing Dart list and need a way to import all un-implemented methods Dart editor is not offering this option like Java eclipse editor. Is there a way to do auto-importing in Dart editor? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean create method stubs instead of importing.

If you add `implements xxx` to a class declaration DartEditor shows a warning on the class name.
You can right-click and choose `implement missing methods` or set the cursor at the word with the yellow underline and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and choose `implement missing methods`.

Comment: I don't remember seeing this before. Was it added recently? I'll check it once I'm back to my desk. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know. It's available for a while. A recent change was that the @override annotation is added automatically (maybe not released yet)

Comment: Nice. That was exactly what I wanted. Thanks.